# How do I update chart cached data in Excel

Tags: .net, openxml-sdk

I have a Excel spreadsheet which gets updated and generates a chart using openXML(c#). The generated excel chart must be updated in powerpoint. I am unable to copy the updated chart to powerpoint unles I open the excel file and save it manually.

I would like to know how to update the chart and the underlying data (Cached data) without having to manually open and save the excel file

Any help/suggestions will be valuable.